# Is the *lingua franca* question to be closed as "General Reference"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, general-reference

This [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/etymology-of-lingua-franca) asks about the etymology of the term *lingua franca*. It can be looked up on Etymonline or Wikipedia with satisfactory result. But this isn't a word definition, and I actually found the top answer interesting to read, though it probably isn't any more informative than Wikipedia or Etymonline.

Should a question like this be closed? From the comments it appears that someone feels quite strongly about it; but, considering that it isn't a plain word-definition question, I'd be inclined to keep it open.

Comment: Related: [What is the General Reference qualification for questions on word or phrase origin?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/what-is-the-general-reference-qualification-for-questions-on-word-or-phrase-origi)

Comment: Having just looked at 'the question' for the first time, I can see something of the dilemma. Particularly in light of the little spat in the associated comments. I agree that particular poster has a tendency to pose questions where I suspect he already knows the answer; he just thinks that answer is interesting. Personally, I always thought the *franca* part just meant *open, accessible*. So I'm interested to know it's from the Frankish tongue. But I'd never have thought to look that up myself, so I'm glad I came across it!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The question per se is interesting, the problem is that it is too basic: You type and you have the answer...

Comment: @Alenanno: Exactly. That's why I said it's a bit of a dilemma. I would never have thought to ask, because of what I thought I already knew - which turned out not to be the case anyway. For me the issue is that it's not really a *question* - it's an interesting little snippet of information. Which, as I said, I suspect the poster already knew when he 'asked'. But I was still happy to have been enlightened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard. The question by itself is general reference. But behind (most) every question, there's an interesting answer.

I think the voting to close takes care of that, you need 5 people to close, if there aren't 5 people to do it then it stays open.

Oh, and I think the strong feelings about closing were motivated by exasperation at multiple similar 'general reference'-looking questions by the same person. (and I think the downvoting should take care of that).

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, I also added a close vote for a few reasons.

- The question showed no attempt to provide *any* help in answering the question. Instead, it claimed an inability to find the history or origin *at all*. Given that even Wikipedia has the etymology listed, it seems apparent that this is as likely of a General Reference etymology question as we are ever to see.
- After trimming out the irrelevant content from the question body, it becomes "What is the etymology of lingua franca?" This isn't a *bad* question, but when the entire body of the question is irrelevant it may be a hint that this type of question is uninteresting. Replacing *lingua franca* with any other word wouldn't change this question's form in the slightest. This seems like a bad precedent.
- I tend to be close happy.

Comment: +1 _"Replacing lingua franca with any other word wouldn't change this question's form in the slightest."_ You have a point there. I voted to close as well. There are other questions that "seem" general reference but it's the _how_ they are being asked that changes everything, see @Billare questions that are really well-posted and intriguing, although sometimes he asks "basic" things... I can't come up with examples now :D